# How to generically call a generic method?

Tags: java, generics

How to perform overloading for a generic method? How can I invoke method 2 from method 1?

```
public interface ByteConsumer{

    // Method 1
    default <T> T consume(T consumer) throws IOException{
        return consume(consumer);
    }

    // Method 2
    default <T extends BaseToBytes> T consume(T consumer) throws IOException {
        consume(consumer.getInputStream());
        return consumer;
    }

    void consume(InputStream input) throws IOException;
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's not a safe cast, but I found an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, found it:

```
@Override
default <T> T consume(T consumer) throws IOException{
    //noinspection unchecked
    return (T) consume((BaseToBytes)consumer);
}
```

Comment: Why even have that method? You're giving up compile time type checking for runtime problems.

Comment: Why would you do that? It would fail for all the types that don't extend BaseToBytes.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I have two different interfaces that are having a different implementation of the consuming method(it has a different signature). I am trying to create a common interface for both of them so I can handle one list of objects from both of the type.

Comment: @JBNizet my comment is the same for you too

Comment: Sounds like a possible XY Problem. Maybe elaborate on your actual use case so we can suggest a proper approach.